# unpack ZXIC chip firmware

Tags: firmware, unpacking

Is it possible to unpack this firmware for ZXIC chipset device?

I tried to unpack it with binwalk but wasn't successful and I saw this information:

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
24264         0x5EC8          uImage header, header size: 64 bytes, header CRC: 0x9F7BA51, created: 2021-12-27 10:36:17, image size: 148376 bytes, Data Address: 0x21EF0000, Entry Point: 0x21EF0000, data CRC: 0xF9C36244, OS: Firmware, CPU: ARM, image type: OS Kernel Image, compression type: none, image name: "ZX297520"
36788         0x8FB4          gzip compressed data, from TOPS/20, last modified: 1970-01-01 00:00:00 (null date)
177172        0x2B414         JFFS2 filesystem, little endian
29234636      0x1BE15CC       uImage header, header size: 64 bytes, header CRC: 0x9F7BA51, created: 2021-12-27 10:36:17, image size: 148376 bytes, Data Address: 0x21EF0000, Entry Point: 0x21EF0000, data CRC: 0xF9C36244, OS: Firmware, CPU: ARM, image type: OS Kernel Image, compression type: none, image name: "ZX297520"
29247160      0x1BE46B8       gzip compressed data, from TOPS/20, last modified: 1970-01-01 00:00:00 (null date)
29383460      0x1C05B24       uImage header, header size: 64 bytes, header CRC: 0x9F7BA51, created: 2021-12-27 10:36:17, image size: 148376 bytes, Data Address: 0x21EF0000, Entry Point: 0x21EF0000, data CRC: 0xF9C36244, OS: Firmware, CPU: ARM, image type: OS Kernel Image, compression type: none, image name: "ZX297520"
29395984      0x1C08C10       gzip compressed data, from TOPS/20, last modified: 1970-01-01 00:00:00 (null date)
```

with hex editor, we can check some internal files packed.
[image]

[firmware link](https://www.mediafire.com/file/3eip1zac4f7yh0m/firmware.bin/file)

Thank you

Comment: Are you using the `-e` flag?

Comment: ok, thanks for your answer,
must i need to use Linux to do it, because jefferson can't install on Windows with python.
And when i use `binwalk -e` it shows this image, but we can't find uboot.bin, z-loader and others files. [![binwalk output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKBjl.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKBjl.png)

Answer (score 3):

Install [jefferson](https://github.com/sviehb/jefferson), which is unpacker for jffs2 file system used in your image, if it is not installed yet, and run  `binwalk -e -M firmware.bin -C [result folder]`

I checked this with your firmware, works fine.
If you have problems with your run try to update your [binwalk](https://github.com/ReFirmLabs/binwalk) and other utilities it uses.

- -M flag is for "matroshka" mode, it will unpack everything potentially unpackable inside the already unpacked images.
- -e is for extraction